# Mac : There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant

Tags: macos, caching, vagrant, virtual-machine, aerospike

I am working with aerospike and installing it using vagrant virtual box.

After installation, when i am trying to start the virtual machine, it is giving the following error:

> . There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
>   for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.
>
> Command: ["startvm", "dff6693e-52c8-4c9e-922a-243d18c7f666", "--type", "headless"]
>
> Stderr: VBoxManage: error: The VM session was closed before any attempt to power it on
>   VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component SessionMachine, interface ISession

i am using mac machine for this setup.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Proceeding with the following steps helped me out:

1. restart the virtual box using:

   ```
   sudo "/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/LaunchDaemons/VirtualBoxStartup.sh" restart
   ```
2. Stop vagrant as follows:

   ```
   vagrant halt
   ```
3. start vagrant as follows:

   ```
   vagrant up
   ```

Comment: just in case this helps someone else, this wasn't enough for me. I had to reboot to get this to work. It took me a while to "give up" and try a reboot.

Answer (score 15):

Go to `settings` => `security & privacy` => `general`

and allow permission.

Comment: Thank you. Basically, you'll see something like "A program from Oracle Inc. was blocked from accessing system... " with an Allow button next to it, click that.

Answer (score 7):

Just had the same issue after latest OS update (Big Sur). Steps I had to get through in order to get it working again:

- Uninstall VirtulBox and reinstall it (it shouldn't delete your VMs)
- run `homestead box update` in Homestead directory
- run `sudo "/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/LaunchDaemons/VirtualBoxStartup.sh" restart`
- Weirdly enough, followed @Alperen Tahta 's link and restarted laptop after I changed permissions.
- Vagrant up and tada!

It took me a few steps to get there but I now have my VMs up and ruinning as before.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

None of the above solutions worked for me. I got this problem after upgrading my Macbook to Ventura 13.
I tried all the above steps, and none worked for me. If you're having the same issue due to an OS upgrade then try the following steps:

1. Make sure the VirtualBox version is >= 7.0.2; if not, uninstall the current version completely, delete all files and folders that relate to VirtualBox and install the current version [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).
2. Make sure to use Vagrant version 2.3.3 or above. If not, uninstall the current version completely, delete all files and folders related to Vagrant and install the current version [here](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vagrant/downloads).

Yep, that should work.

Answer (score 1):

For macos you can update privaciy and security permissions.

here is a link:
https://medium.com/@Aenon/mac-virtualbox-kernel-driver-error-df39e7e10cd8

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You can simply restart your system and then restart Vagrant as well. The error majorly occurs when the virtual box was stopped abruptly.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

1. Open up the VirtualBox GUI and look at "older" items in the VirtualBox Manager.
2. Remove all the boxes that are written 'inaccessible'
3. `sudo "/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/LaunchDaemons/VirtualBoxStartup.sh" restart`
4. `vagrant halt`
5. `vagrant up`