# Vagrant setup error: There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant for controlling VirtualBox

Tags: macos, vagrant, virtual-machine, vagrantfile, macos-big-sur

i am new to coding and am currently facing an annoying issue when installing Vagrant
and it is stopping from completing my studies, i am using:

> macOS Big Sur 11.3.1 on a MacPro

I've tried uninstalling / installing both Vagrant and Virtualbox using their own websites and using brew, but no luck so far to solve the below issue.

```
vagrant --version
Vagrant 2.2.16
```

Here is log from my terminal (also tried using iTerm but the same issue):

```
vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'bento/ubuntu-16.04-i386' version '2.3.5' is up to date...
==> default: A newer version of the box 'bento/ubuntu-16.04-i386' is available and already
==> default: installed, but your Vagrant machine is running against
==> default: version '2.3.5'. To update to version '202102.02.0',
==> default: destroy and recreate your machine.
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 8000 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 8080 (guest) => 8080 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 5000 (guest) => 5000 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "1c862e17-0e9e-475d-8b1c-7df81fc3b144", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage: error: The virtual machine 'vagrant_default_1621523735226_48464' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3DZq.jpg)

I trying to vagrant up this [file](https://s3.amazonaws.com/video.udacity-data.com/topher/2018/April/5acfbfa3_fsnd-virtual-machine/fsnd-virtual-machine.zip) from my course materials, and i just download it and change the directory with "cd" to the folder with the vagrant file then to vagrant up.

Thank you so much,

UPDATE:

I tired the some of the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54286934/15984121) but it didn't work too, and when i tried the below code i got a lot of error messages.

> sudo "/Library/Application
> Support/VirtualBox/LaunchDaemons/VirtualBoxStartup.sh" restart

```
sudo "/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/LaunchDaemons/VirtualBoxStartup.sh" restart

Password:
Loading VBoxDrv.kext
Error Domain=KMErrorDomain Code=71 "Incompatible architecture: Binary is for x86_64, but needed arch arm64e" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Incompatible architecture: Binary is for x86_64, but needed arch arm64e}
Error: Failed to load org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv
Loading VBoxUSB.kext
Error Domain=KMErrorDomain Code=71 "Incompatible architecture: Binary is for x86_64, but needed arch arm64e" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Incompatible architecture: Binary is for x86_64, but needed arch arm64e}
Error: Failed to load org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB
Loading VBoxNetFlt.kext
Error Domain=KMErrorDomain Code=71 "Incompatible architecture: Binary is for x86_64, but needed arch arm64e" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Incompatible architecture: Binary is for x86_64, but needed arch arm64e}
Error: Failed to load org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt
Loading VBoxNetAdp.kext
Error Domain=KMErrorDomain Code=71 "Incompatible architecture: Binary is for x86_64, but needed arch arm64e" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Incompatible architecture: Binary is for x86_64, but needed arch arm64e}
Error: Failed to load org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp
Executing: /usr/bin/kmutil unload -b org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp
Error Domain=KMErrorDomain Code=3 "Error occurred unloading extensions: Missing extension with identifier org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp : Incompatible architecture: Binary is for x86_64, but needed arch arm64e" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Error occurred unloading extensions: Missing extension with identifier org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp : Incompatible architecture: Binary is for x86_64, but needed arch arm64e}
Executing: /usr/bin/kmutil unload -b org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt
Error Domain=KMErrorDomain Code=3 "Error occurred unloading extensions: Missing extension with identifier org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt : Incompatible architecture: Binary is for x86_64, but needed arch arm64e" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Error occurred unloading extensions: Missing extension with identifier org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt : Incompatible architecture: Binary is for x86_64, but needed arch arm64e}
Executing: /usr/bin/kmutil unload -b org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB
Error Domain=KMErrorDomain Code=3 "Error occurred unloading extensions: Missing extension with identifier org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB : Incompatible architecture: Binary is for x86_64, but needed arch arm64e" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Error occurred unloading extensions: Missing extension with identifier org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB : Incompatible architecture: Binary is for x86_64, but needed arch arm64e}
Executing: /usr/bin/kmutil unload -b org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv
Error Domain=KMErrorDomain Code=3 "Error occurred unloading extensions: Missing extension with identifier org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv : Incompatible architecture: Binary is for x86_64, but needed arch arm64e" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Error occurred unloading extensions: Missing extension with identifier org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv : Incompatible architecture: Binary is for x86_64, but needed arch arm64e}
Fatal error: VirtualBox
```

Comment: Do you have a new mac with an M1 chip? That might be what's causing the issue. See this thread for details https://www.reddit.com/r/virtualbox/comments/lelvjy/virtualbox_m1_apple_i_hate_this/

Comment: Have you solved? I met the same problem.